# DI outside the constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

Can we request dependencies on the fly in .NET Core? Something like:

```
public void MyMethod() {
    var dep = DependencyMagic.Instantiate<MyDependency>();
}
```

I'm not interested in a 3rd party solution, but feel free to comment on them if it completes your answer. I'm just using the DI built into .NET Core. I can't use [`Activator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx) because I don't know what the signature of the dependency's constructor will be.

Comment: What DI engine are you using, a built in one or a third party library?

Comment: Make sure you aren't applying the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: @Steven, my example is oversimplified. I've been reading through your stuff, and the `QueryProcessor` in [this post](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) does something similar, but with a different DI solution. My question is how to do the same thing with .NET Core's built-in DI.

Comment: Ah okay, so you encapsulated the call inside your Composition Root. That's fine. How to do this however with .NET Core DI, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use instance of `System.IServiceProvider`. It defines next method:

```
// Gets the service object of the specified type.
public object GetService(Type serviceType)
```

in .NET Core [this](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.cs) extension method also is provided:

```
public static T GetService<T>(this IServiceProvider provider)
```

and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScope.ServiceProvider` ([definition](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs)) is the default implementation of `IServiceProvider` interface.

If you application is an ASP.NET Core, then having `HttpContext` you can retrieve `IServiceProvider` instance. From [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) documentation:

> The services available within an ASP.NET request from HttpContext are exposed through the RequestServices collection.

[image]

> Request Services represent the services you configure and request as part of your application. When your objects specify dependencies, these are satisfied by the types found in RequestServices, not ApplicationServices.
>
> Generally, you shouldn't use these properties directly, preferring instead to request the types your classes you require via your class's constructor, and letting the framework inject these dependencies. This yields classes that are easier to test (see Testing) and are more loosely coupled.

Comment: I came to the same solution. It does introduce a dependency on the specific DI solution, but that's a trade-off I can accept and can work around easily enough if it does become an issue.